# Pip package install with preinstalled dependencies

Tags: python, django, pip, django-cms

I would like to install some python packages from local directories (downloaded from GitHub) specified in `requirements.txt`

```
-e ./src/django-django-eca4737
-e ./src/divio-django-appmedia-55835b6
-e ./src/ojii-django-sekizai-25c64f4
-e ./src/ojii-django-classy-tags-f2076f6
-e ./src/theatlantic-django-south-471b16b
-e ./src/etianen-django-reversion-bdb9e8e
-e ./src/django-mptt-django-mptt-7d3e111
-e ./src/jezdez-django-appconf-53c5de7
-e ./src/jezdez-django_compressor-c726239
-e ./src/mongodb-mongo-python-driver-fcb88ee
-e ./src/divio-django-cms-66fbff0
PIL
wsgiref
```

However, after pip installs the packages from the local directories (`pip install -r requirements.txt`), it also installs them from remote repos as DjangoCMS dependencies (same versions!). How to avoid this?

Comment: Just being curious: Why would you do this? Offline distribution? Version freezing? If the later, why not better fork those Github repositories with your account, and the make Pip install from them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `--no-dependencies` or just `--no-deps` option

```
pip install --no-dependencies -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: What if you want to only ignore the dependencies of one package within requirements.txt?

Comment: You can try to install this package before all requirements and probably edit requirements.txt